# C function pointers error storage class specified for parameter `type name'

Tags: c, gcc, callback, function-pointers, nesc

I currently have a piece of code that I am working on using function pointers as callbacks.  I am having trouble with an error from gcc stating "storage class specified for parameter `type name'"  The relevant portion of code is:

```
error_t addCommand(uint8_t command, void  (*callback)(uint16_t,uint8_t)){
```

This is actually using the nesC language for TinyOS but it seems to be a C issue.  In my research on the issue I have found suggestions mostly stemming from one of two issues:

1. Something wrong in a header (missing semicolon)
2. Passing a function pointer with a static or volatile value (i.e. `void (*callback)(volatile int, uint8_t)`

I have eliminated problem 1 as far as I can tell.  Problem 2 is only an issue if `uint16_t` or `uint8_t` are static of volatile (I don't have much experience with these types).  Any tips/answers on how to solve this issue are greatly appreciated.

Also, if anyone is familiar with nesC the exact code looks more like this:

```
command error_t CommandEngine.addCommand(uint8_t command,
                                         void  (*callback)(uint16_t,uint8_t)) {
```

It may be possible that what nesC is adding to the C language causes this error but I don't think this is the case.

EDIT:  It was nesC, in a way.  It turns out that I'm a moron and was using command as a variable name when command is used by nesC and converted to some block of C code before compilation.  Thanks everyone for the idea of converting it to C code as this caused me to realize the issue.  I really should have thought of this.

Comment: void  (*callback)(uint16_t,uint8_t) - Isn't it just a type? Shouldn't we be having a parameter name here during function definition?

Comment: Another storage class is `extern`, so look to see if there's a case of `extern` not being used correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally good to use typedefs for function pointers. It may solve your problem, and will surely be much more readable:

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(uint16_t,uint8_t);
error_t addCommand(uint8_t command, callback_t callback)){
```

If it won't solve the problem, it will at least narrow it down - you'll see if the problem is with the typedef or the function.

You should also try to figure out if it's nesC (which I know nothing about) or C. Try to remove nesC specific parts and compile with gcc, and see what happens.

Comment: While the other comments also helped by mentioning this,  removing nesC specific parts caused me to realize that I had used a reserved word in nesC (command) as a function argument name.  This was getting expanded into some block of C prior to being sent to the gcc compiler.  Thank you.